# How to evaluate $\int\frac{xe^{x}}{x^{2} + 1}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I solve  this integral?

$$\int\frac{xe^{x}}{x^{2} + 1}\,dx$$

Comment: The header question doesn't match the question in the body.  Which is intended?

Comment: Note:  the header question can be done by parts.  I doubt the other has a pleasant solution.

Comment: The question in the body may be done with the geometric series followed by incomplete gamma functions when $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 3):

By geometric series, we have

$$\frac1{1+r^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nr^{2n}$$

Thus, by letting $x=-u$, we find that

$$\begin{align}I&=\int_0^{-a}\frac{xe^x}{1+x^2}\ dx\\&=\int_0^a\frac{ue^{-u}}{1+u^2}\ du\\&=\int_0^a\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nu^{2n+1}e^{-u}\ du\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\int_0^au^{2n+1}e^{-u}\ du\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\gamma(2n+1,a)\end{align}$$

where we use the [lower incomplete gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html).  This series converges for $|a|<1$.

---

I also speculate closed form does not exist.  [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20xe%5Ex%2F(1%2Bx%5E2)) gives a solution in terms of complex exponential integrals though.

Comment: (+1) $$\frac{x}{x^2+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x+i}+\frac{1}{x-i}\right)$$ is the reason for the last paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to get to [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(xe%5Ex)%2F(x%5E2%2B1))'s solution containing [Exponential Integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral):

---

Let's use partial fractions:
$$\int \frac{xe^x}{x^2+1}~dx=\int e^x \cdot \frac{x}{x^2+1}~dx$$
Note that I split the fraction so we could use the ansatz:
$$\frac{x}{x^2+1}=\frac{A}{x+i}+\frac{B}{x-i}$$
You should find that $A=B=\frac{1}{2}$.
Therefore, we have:
$$\begin{align}\int e^x \cdot \frac{x}{x^2+1}~dx&=\frac{1}{2}\int e^x\left(\frac{1}{x+i}+\frac{1}{x-i}\right)~dx\\&=\frac{1}{2} \color{red}{\int \frac{e^x}{x+i}~dx}+\frac{1}{2}\color{green}{\int \frac{e^x}{x-i}~dx} \end{align}$$
The two integrals can easily be solved. For the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ integral, use the substitution $u=x+i$, and for the $\color{green}{\text{green}}$ integral, use the substitution $v=x-i$.

---

Here, I will do the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ integral:
$$\int \frac{e^x}{x+i}~dx=\int \frac{e^{u-i}}{u}~du=\frac{1}{e^i}\int \frac{e^u}{u}~du=\frac{1}{e^i}\cdot \operatorname*{Ei}(u)+C=\frac{\operatorname*{Ei}(x+i)}{e^i}+C$$
The $\color{green}{\text{green}}$ integral can be solved in a similar way:

$$\int \frac{e^x}{x-i}~dx=\int \frac{e^{v+i}}{v}~dv=e^i\int \frac{e^v}{v}~dv=e^i\cdot \operatorname*{Ei}(v)+C=e^i\cdot \operatorname*{Ei}(x-i)+C$$
Combining these two results, we obtain:
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int \frac{xe^x}{x^2+1}~dx=\frac{\operatorname*{Ei}(x+i)}{2e^i}+\frac{e^i\cdot \operatorname*{Ei}(x-i)}{2}+C}$$

Comment: how do u get the red there??

Comment: @AlexanderDay use \color{red}{math stuff}.